# How to use Map in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

> I want implement maphash but not know hashmap
>   I am Noob in programming
>   I tried Hashmap `(`animal`)`
>   I be testing in site oficial kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map use key/value

example:
var map = hashMapOf("animal" to "hiberne")
"animal" -> "hiberne"

add : map.put("key", "value")
remove: map.remove("key")